# Side bar: navbar does not display toggle button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am using to bootstrap 3 with navbar and sidebar template.
I placed Navbar inside the main part.
You can see original template in [bootply editor](http://www.bootply.com/new), select sidebar template.
I replaced its css with [offcanvas.css](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/offcanvas.css) see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agcsi/z4e7wmy9/)
The issues (occurs in original template as well) in Safari on ipad air iOS 7.1.3:
Button to open/close side bar does not show up when screen is small enough. On android: kit kat, chrome it works fine.

Here is the style:

```
html,
        body {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
        /* * Off Canvas * ---- */

        @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
            .row-offcanvas {
                -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
                -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
                position: relative;
                transition: all .25s ease-out;
            }

            .row-offcanvas-right { right: 0; }

            .row-offcanvas-left { left: 0; }

            .row-offcanvas-right .sidebar-offcanvas {
                right: -50%; /* 6 columns */
            }

            .row-offcanvas-left .sidebar-offcanvas {
                left: -50%; /* 6 columns */
            }

            .row-offcanvas-right.active {
                right: 50%; /* 6 columns */
            }

            .row-offcanvas-left.active {
                left: 50%; /* 6 columns */
            }

            .sidebar-offcanvas {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                width: 50%; /* 6 columns */
            }
        }
    </style>
```

Here is html:

```
<div class="page-container">        
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">                    
                <!-- sidebar -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation" ng-controller="LeftPaneCtrl">
                    <tabset>
                        <!--                    class="nav-tab"-->
                        <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
                            <tab-heading ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">{{tab.title}}</tab-heading>
                            <div>
                                <!--                            class="nav-tab-content"-->
                                <div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
                            </div>
                        </tab>
                    </tabset>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                    <!-- top navbar -->
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                </div>
                <!-- main area -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" ng-controller="MainViewCtrl">
                    Main View
                </div><!-- /.col-xs-12 main -->
            </div><!--/.row-->
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </div><!--/.page-container-->
```

Comment: What happens when you change the col-xs widths to match the col-sm widths? I.e., what if you use `col-xs-3` and `col-xs-9` instead?

Comment: same behavior, i updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agcsi/z4e7wmy9/1/

Answer (score 1):

I found what went wrong.
I changed `@media screen and (max-width: 768px)`  to `@media screen and (max-width: 800px)` however looking at navbar-toggle class in bootstrap it has

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-toggle {
display: none;
}
```

so that's where the issue comes from